An estimation of Bezout Coefficients(produced by Extended Euclidean Algorithm) on Gaussian integers
Problem: Suppose that for two given Gaussian integers $a$ and $b\ (|a|>|b|>0)$, there exists $a_0$ such that the remainder of the Euclidean division of $a_0$ by $a$ is exactly $b$. If it takes $n$ steps to calculate their Bezout coefficients $x$ and $y$ produced by Extended Euclidean Algorithm($ax+by=d$), prove that (or give a counterexample?)
\begin{align}
F_{n-1} &\leq|x|\leq\frac{\sqrt 2}2\bigg(\bigg|\frac b d\bigg|-F_{n-2}\bigg),\\
F_n&\leq|y|\leq\frac{\sqrt 2}2\bigg(\bigg|\frac a d\bigg|-F_{n-1}\bigg),
\end{align}
where $\{F_n\}$ denotes the number sequence $F_0=0,F_1=1,F_{n+2}=\sqrt 2F_{n+1}+F_n$.
Note: When using the Euclidean division for Gaussian integers $a=qb+r$, assume that $\frac a b=m+in, m,n\in \mathbb Q$, we take $q=\lceil m-\frac 1 2\rceil+i\lceil n-\frac 1 2\rceil$ and $r=a-qb$.
Example:
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
a&=12+i,\\
b&=4+5i,\\
a_0&=16+6i,
\end{aligned}\right.
\Rightarrow
\left\{\begin{aligned}
x&=3i,\\
y&=-4-4i.
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
The algorithm takes 4 steps to calculate $x$ and $y$, and they satisfy the inequalities above.
My confusion: If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then this proposition has another form that can be proved using the induction method:

For two given positive integers $a$ and $b\ (a>b>0)$, if it takes $n$ steps to calculate their Bezout coefficients $x$ and $y$ produced by Extended Euclidean Algorithm($ax+by=d$), prove that
\begin{align}
F_{n-1} &\leq|x|\leq\frac 1 2\bigg(\frac b d-F_{n-2}\bigg),\\
F_n&\leq|y|\leq\frac 1 2\bigg(\frac a d-F_{n-1}\bigg),
\end{align}
where $\{F_n\}$ denotes Fibonacci Sequence.

However the similar method just won't work fo Gaussian integers.

what is the source of the problem?

The proposition on positive integers is from a reading material (however I can only find the Chinese version to it, you can refer to here), and I am trying to generalize it on Gaussian integers.

Alright. I found two references; you are using Caviness-Collins. I found Rolletschek more interesting. Meanwhile, there could be many more recent articles, even books that have this. For example, Henri Cohen has books on computational number theory.   Meanwhile, I believe that all you really need to understand is the sequence    $$ ; \frac{1-i}{1}, ; \frac{3}{1+i},  ; \frac{4(1-i)}{3}, ; \frac{11}{4(1+i)}, ; \frac{15(1-i)}{11}, ; \frac{41}{15(1+i)},  ; \frac{56(1-i)}{41}, ; \frac{153}{56(1+i)}, $$

I recommend  https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3754 . Section 5 is Growth Properties of the Convergents

Notes: you are using the Caviness-Collins(1976)  rule for selecting the quotient. In Rolletschek (1986)  he demands the minimal-norm   quotient, which is what I am doing. I did a massive run looking for CF's (Continued Fractions)   of  increasing length. What stood out, eventually, was a repetition in the "partial quotients."  Instead of the  repeated quotient $1$  in the CF for consecutive (real) Fibonacci numbers, here the repeated pair $1-i, 1+i$  was omnipresent.
Sequence that illustrates the limiting behavior they want.
Not quite as pretty as the consecutive Fibonacci numbers for ordinary integers.
$$ \; \frac{1-i}{1}, \; \frac{3}{1+i},  \; \frac{4(1-i)}{3}, \; \frac{11}{4(1+i)}, \; \frac{15(1-i)}{11}, \; \frac{41}{15(1+i)},  \; \frac{56(1-i)}{41}, \; \frac{153}{56(1+i)},   \; \frac{209(1-i)}{153}, \; \frac{571}{209(1+i)},  $$
The limit of this sequence is $\frac{1+ \sqrt 3}{2} \; (1-i). \;$   If you take the complex conjugate of the sequence, that limit is $\frac{1+ \sqrt 3}{2} \; (1+i). \;$
Note that each consecutive pair of convergents has a "cross-product"   of $\pm 1.$ As in :  $(1-i) (1+i) -1 \cdot 3 = -1$  Next $3 \cdot 3 - (1+i) \cdot 4(1-i) = 1$ Next $4(1-i) \cdot 4 (1+i) - 3 \cdot 11 = -1$  Next $11 \cdot 11 - 4(1+i) \cdot 15(1-i) = 1.$ These show you the Bezout coordinates for each ratio, namely the numerator and denominator of the preceding ratio.
The recurrence for either the numerators or the denominators is
$$    N_{j+4}  = 4N_{j+2}  - N_j  $$
$$    D_{j+4}  = 4D_{j+2}  - D_j  $$
sequence of ratios of Gaussian integers, with increasing length of Euclidean algorithm, as computed below
Wed 03 Jul 2024 08:11:36 PM PDT
1. ( 1 + -1 i  )  = ( 1 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 0 + 0 i  )

1. ( 3 + 0 i  )  = ( 1 + 1 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 1 + 0 i  )
2. ( 1 + 1 i  )  = ( 1 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 0 + 0 i  )

1. ( 4 + -4 i  )  = ( 3 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 1 + -1 i  )
2. ( 3 + 0 i  )  = ( 1 + -1 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 1 + 0 i  )
3. ( 1 + -1 i  )  = ( 1 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 0 + 0 i  )

1. ( 11 + 0 i  )  = ( 4 + 4 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 3 + 0 i  )
2. ( 4 + 4 i  )  = ( 3 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 1 + 1 i  )
3. ( 3 + 0 i  )  = ( 1 + 1 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 1 + 0 i  )
4. ( 1 + 1 i  )  = ( 1 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 0 + 0 i  )

1. ( 15 + -15 i  )  = ( 11 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 4 + -4 i  )
2. ( 11 + 0 i  )  = ( 4 + -4 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 3 + 0 i  )
3. ( 4 + -4 i  )  = ( 3 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 1 + -1 i  )
4. ( 3 + 0 i  )  = ( 1 + -1 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 1 + 0 i  )
5. ( 1 + -1 i  )  = ( 1 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 0 + 0 i  )

1. ( 41 + 0 i  )  = ( 15 + 15 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 11 + 0 i  )
2. ( 15 + 15 i  )  = ( 11 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 4 + 4 i  )
3. ( 11 + 0 i  )  = ( 4 + 4 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 3 + 0 i  )
4. ( 4 + 4 i  )  = ( 3 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 1 + 1 i  )
5. ( 3 + 0 i  )  = ( 1 + 1 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 1 + 0 i  )
6. ( 1 + 1 i  )  = ( 1 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 0 + 0 i  )

1. ( 56 + -56 i  )  = ( 41 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 15 + -15 i  )
2. ( 41 + 0 i  )  = ( 15 + -15 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 11 + 0 i  )
3. ( 15 + -15 i  )  = ( 11 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 4 + -4 i  )
4. ( 11 + 0 i  )  = ( 4 + -4 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 3 + 0 i  )
5. ( 4 + -4 i  )  = ( 3 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 1 + -1 i  )
6. ( 3 + 0 i  )  = ( 1 + -1 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 1 + 0 i  )
7. ( 1 + -1 i  )  = ( 1 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 0 + 0 i  )

1. ( 153 + 0 i  )  = ( 56 + 56 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 41 + 0 i  )
2. ( 56 + 56 i  )  = ( 41 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 15 + 15 i  )
3. ( 41 + 0 i  )  = ( 15 + 15 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 11 + 0 i  )
4. ( 15 + 15 i  )  = ( 11 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 4 + 4 i  )
5. ( 11 + 0 i  )  = ( 4 + 4 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 3 + 0 i  )
6. ( 4 + 4 i  )  = ( 3 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 1 + 1 i  )
7. ( 3 + 0 i  )  = ( 1 + 1 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 1 + 0 i  )
8. ( 1 + 1 i  )  = ( 1 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 0 + 0 i  )

1. ( 209 + -209 i  )  = ( 153 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 56 + -56 i  )
2. ( 153 + 0 i  )  = ( 56 + -56 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 41 + 0 i  )
3. ( 56 + -56 i  )  = ( 41 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 15 + -15 i  )
4. ( 41 + 0 i  )  = ( 15 + -15 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 11 + 0 i  )
5. ( 15 + -15 i  )  = ( 11 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 4 + -4 i  )
6. ( 11 + 0 i  )  = ( 4 + -4 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 3 + 0 i  )
7. ( 4 + -4 i  )  = ( 3 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 1 + -1 i  )
8. ( 3 + 0 i  )  = ( 1 + -1 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 1 + 0 i  )
9. ( 1 + -1 i  )  = ( 1 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 0 + 0 i  )

1. ( 571 + 0 i  )  = ( 209 + 209 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 153 + 0 i  )
2. ( 209 + 209 i  )  = ( 153 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 56 + 56 i  )
3. ( 153 + 0 i  )  = ( 56 + 56 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 41 + 0 i  )
4. ( 56 + 56 i  )  = ( 41 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 15 + 15 i  )
5. ( 41 + 0 i  )  = ( 15 + 15 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 11 + 0 i  )
6. ( 15 + 15 i  )  = ( 11 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 4 + 4 i  )
7. ( 11 + 0 i  )  = ( 4 + 4 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 3 + 0 i  )
8. ( 4 + 4 i  )  = ( 3 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 1 + 1 i  )
9. ( 3 + 0 i  )  = ( 1 + 1 i  ) * ( 1 + -1 i  ) + ( 1 + 0 i  )
10. ( 1 + 1 i  )  = ( 1 + 0 i  ) * ( 1 + 1 i  ) + ( 0 + 0 i  )

